# Getting a max value for every id given in query (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query like this

```
select distinct on (foreign_id) foreign_id, id, date
from table
where foreign_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

I am getting result as

| foreign_id | id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 2019-03-20 |
| 2 | 102 | 2020-02-06 |
| 3 | 103 | 2020-06-09 |

Which is good because I want to get only single row every foreign_id but I would like to get row with max date and max id value in result.

Right now for id number 1 I am getting date 2019-03-20 which is not the greatest date that is in table

I have tried to use max() function but It returns only one row from one given foreign_id

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an ORDER BY:

```
select distinct on (foreign_id) foreign_id, id, date
from table
where foreign_id IN (1, 2, 3)
order by foreign_id, date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select select foreign_id, id, date from
(select foreign_id, id, date, 
        row_number() over (partition by foreign_id order by date desc) as rn
   from table
  where foreign_id IN (1, 2, 3) ) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `ORDER BY` clause, because `DISTINCT ON` takes the first record of an *ordered* group.

```
select distinct on (foreign_id) foreign_id, id, date
     from table
     where foreign_id IN (1, 2, 3)
     order by foreign_id, date desc <<--- add this
```

Comment: @ArthurV Please don't forget to UPVOTE every helpful answer (point into the right direction, solve the problem) which honors the time and effort the repliers invested into your problem. If one answer completely solves your question, please ACCEPT it additionally to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through cte and row_number() as below:

```
with cte as (
select foreign_id,id,date, row_number()over (partition by foreign_id order by date desc) rownum
    from t
    )
    select foreign_id,id,date from cte where rownum=1
```